# Postfix to Infix

Tags: java, stack, infix-notation

I'm trying to convert a postfix into an infix. I have some code, but I'm not able to fix it. There may be a condition I am missing. Or my structure is not quite right.
Also since I am new to Java I may need some help with "`Stack<Character>`".

```
public static String postfixToInfix(String postfix) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack();
    Stack<Character> backup = new Stack();
    StringBuilder infix = new StringBuilder(postfix.length());
    infix.append('(');
    for (int i = 0; i < postfix.length(); i++) {
        if (!isOperator(postfix.charAt(i))) {
            stack.push(postfix.charAt(i));
        } else {
            if (stack.size() == 1 ) {                               //stack is 1
                backup.push(postfix.charAt(i));
            }
            if (stack.size() == 0 && backup.size()%5 == 0) {        //stack is 0
                stack.push(backup.pop());
                stack.push(backup.pop());
                stack.push(backup.pop());
                stack.push(backup.pop());
                stack.push(backup.pop());
                stack.push(postfix.charAt(i));
            }
            if (stack.size() >= 2) {                                //stack is > 1
                char arg2 = stack.pop();
                char arg1 = stack.pop();
                backup.push(')');
                backup.push(arg2);
                backup.push(postfix.charAt(i));
                backup.push(arg1);
                backup.push('(');
            }
        }
    }

    while (!backup.empty()) { //only size 3
        stack.push(backup.pop());
    }
    while (!stack.empty()) { //only size 3
        backup.push(stack.pop());
    }
    while (!backup.isEmpty()) {
        infix.append(backup.pop());
    }
    infix.append(')');
    return infix.toString();
}

private static boolean isOperator(char c) {
        return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '^' || c == '(' || c == ')';
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String infix1 = "(3-(7*2))";
        String postfix1 = "372*-";
        String infix2 = "((7+1)*((3-6)*(5-2)))";
        String postfix2 = "71+36-52-**";

        System.out.println("                postfix1: " + postfix1);
        s = postfixToInfix(postfix1);
        System.out.println("postfixToInfix(postfix1): " + s);
        if (s.equals(infix1)) {
            System.out.println("                       Korrekt!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("                       Nicht korrekt!");
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("                postfix2: " + postfix2);
        s = postfixToInfix(postfix2);
        System.out.println("postfixToInfix(postfix2): " + s);
        if (s.equals(infix2)) {
            System.out.println("                       Korrekt!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("                       Nicht korrekt!");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output

```
                postfix1: 372*-
postfixToInfix(postfix1): (3-(7*2))
                       Korrekt!

                postfix2: 71+36-52-**
postfixToInfix(postfix2): ((5(-*2)()**)(3-6)(7+1))
                       Nicht korrekt!


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: So in essence, your code is not behaving as you'd expect it should, and you have no idea why. In this situation, you need to do some debugging, best with a debugger, or if you desire, with a lot of println statements sprinkled throughout your code, but the key is that you need to know the state of your key variables as the code is running to give you a clue as to what could be wrong.

Comment: I did debug. Basically I am sitting on this for two days and I'd like to go forward, because I have two other tasks based on this. I also wrote this as pseudo code to keep out the trouble I have with Java itself. Nothing helped so far.

Comment: If you've debugged then please show the fruits of this effort. As written I fear that your question is too vague and broad, and risks being closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of dealing with the parenthesis and everything as separate entries in the stack, you could use strings to simplify the process:

```
private static boolean isOperator(char c) {
    return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '^';
}

public static String postfixToInfix(String postfix) {
    Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
    for (char c : postfix.toCharArray()) {
        if (isOperator(c)) {
            String temp = s.pop();
            s.push('(' + s.pop() + c + temp + ')');
        } else {
            s.push(String.valueOf(c));
        }
    }
    return s.pop();
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I learned something new. I didn't know about the Stack<String> (Like I said - Java newbie). I'll try to apply it to the remaining tasks too. Thanks a lot, again.